# Sitecore - Confirmation before unpublishing root folder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

Consider:

[image]

Is there a way we can prompt with a confirmation alert in case the root folder is selected to be unpublished?

*Publish* → *restriction (Change)* → *Publishing Settings* → *"Publishable"* check box false get an alert "not to unpublish the root folder.

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"false get an alert"*? Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65325668/edit) it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can disable root unpublish with the following steps.

1. Select the "root item"
2. Take the “Configure” tab from the menu
3. Click on the “Protect Item”

To test this, go to the “Publish” tab then click on “View”. You will see the “Publishable” checkbox disabled.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to lock the item. Then no one can unpublish it. https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/lock-and-unlock-an-item.html

Comment: This method not to be needed. I need a customize method, like when we going to unpublish a root folder. The publishable checkbox untick a user show an alerted "not to unpublish the root folder." @chris